# write xls cel in existing file without overwriting rest file

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to update a single cell in an existing `excel` file.
Here is my code:

```
file=(r'C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.xls')
df=pd.read_excel(file)
code=input('Patiste Kodiko:')
size=0
sizeint=int(input('Patiste Noumero:'))
given=int(input('Posa efigan?:'))
oldstock=(df[size].where(df['ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ']==code))
oldstock=oldstock.dropna()
oldstock=oldstock.values[0]
oldstock = int(oldstock)
newstock = oldstock - given
x=(df['Α/Α'].where(df['ΚΩΔΙΚΟΣ']==code)+2)
x=x.dropna()
x = int(x)
dffin=df.at[x,size] = newstock
dffin.to_excel(file)
close()
```

After running this code, I receive an empty `.xls` file with only one cell written and everything else empty.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do a quick df.at function if you have your X and y cords or names.

```
import pandas as pd
fileLocation = (r'TestExcelsheet.xlsx')
excel = pd.read_excel(FileLocation,converters={'NimikeNro':str})
excel.dtypes
print(excel.index)
print(excel.head)

excel.at[1,'One'] = 444

print(excel)
excel.to_excel('TestExcelsheet.xlsx')
```

Where it's the Excel.at function you need to use to add data at a single cell and use a for loop for more than one cell

Comment: thanks im gonna give it a try. Just one question. What 'nimikerNro' is?

Comment: sry leftover from another projevt where i have a collumn named nimikeNro and i am converting everything in that collumn to str values

Comment: thanki it worked perfect !! Thank you I found my fault!